# batch script that enables proxy server on company network and disable on any other network automatically when laptop starts

Tags: batch-file, proxy, squid

so here is my scenario,i installed squid proxy server on my windows server 2012 domain.and i created the batch files for clients when they turn on laptops on my network and run batch file to enable squid proxy server on their laptops.
which will add ip and port to their browser and  also enable that.
batch file script are as follow:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^
/v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d 192.168.10.2:3128 /f

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^
/v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f**
```

And when they move to any other network or their home network,they need to disable proxy server for browsing,
The file for disabling proxy server from their browsers are as follow:

```
@ECHO OFF
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^
/v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f**
```

Now the problem is sometimes employees forget to run batch file on company network or they don't want to run batch file on network and use internet without running the batch file / enabling proxy.

So I want batch file that runs at startup and check for the network whether thats home network or a company network.and on company network when employees turns on their laptops it will be enabled automatically and when they turn on any other network or work from home that will automatically disable that proxy.
any help will be appreciated,waiting for your kind response.

Thank you

Comment: at startup would not always work. the Wifi might be disconnected and user manually connects well after startup.

Comment: best you use a [proxy auto configuration script](https://superuser.com/questions/45871/can-i-make-windows-7-change-my-proxy-settings-based-on-my-network-connection)

Comment: Thanks Gerhard.
will this script will be configured on windows server 2012 r2 or on employees mechines?

Comment: try this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985352.aspx) for some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The following script works for me. You simply need to change the IP address and port. Copy and paste the code below and save as "Proxy.bat"

```
@echo off
cls
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ ^| findstr "REG_SZ"') do set currentValue=%%a
echo %currentValue%
echo
echo Select:
echo [1] I am at work
echo [2] I am at home
:choice
SET /P C=[Please enter a number]?
for %%? in (1) do if /I "%C%=="%%?" goto 1
for %%? in (2) do if /I "%C%=="%%?" goto 2

:1
@echo off
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d 192.168.85.129:3128 /f
goto end

:2
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
goto end

:end
```

The first few line is to check the proxy address and port in the registry. Next part is to select the choices between the two. I assume the one need proxy is in the office (choice 1). I will turn off the proxy when I am at home (choice 2). Note that when the proxy setting is set by a script, the graphical user interface in the LAN setting will not be affected. You will not see that the proxy has been set, that is why the first few lines is to check the current proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This simple script that worked for me.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.10.0", "255.255.255.0"))
return "PROXY 192.168.10.2:3128";
else
return "DIRECT";
}
```

i added this above script to notepad and save as proxy.pac in C:/ drive.and also give the path in web browser(Chrome) (Setting=>Advanced=>Open Proxy Setting=>Lan Setting) and then tick mark "Use automatic configuration script" and give the path to Proxy.pac file in C:\ drive.
So it detects proxy automatically on my network.and on other networks direct the traffic bypassing the proxy.pac file.
thanks for cooperation.

Comment: Now this above configuration works for me.now i have another trouble when i configure that script on C# developers browsers.they cannot debug their projects that are configured on their local mechines.
when they debug their project squid block that "http://localhost:2270/"
i think i need to do some additional code in this file.i don't have idea about java script.i need help.any body help will me appreciated.
waiting for your kind response.